# Clicking an element on a page through extension and getting the number of elements clicked on the pop-up

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to create a chrome extension that will click on an element on a webpage when you click a on the extension and also it shows the number of elements clicked on the pop up. This following code is only for clicking on the elements in the open tabs. I want to add more functionality where the pop-up shows the number of elements clicked. Need code for that

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Dig Dug",  
    "description": "Label Non-Defective Counts",  
    "version": "1.0",    
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"],      
"browser_action": {         
"default_icon": {
            "19": "icons/19.png",
            "38": "icons/38.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "popup.html"  
    },

    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/16.png",
        "19": "icons/19.png",
        "38": "icons/38.png",
        "64": "icons/64.png",
        "128": "icons/128.png"
    }
}
```

Content Script:

```
function clickNonDefective() {
    var clickNonDefective = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn btn-outline-success"),
    clickNonDefective = clickNonDefective[clickNonDefective];    
    document.getElementById("submit-non-defective-button").click();
}
clickNonDefective();
```

Comment: Please add your problem (error message or description) to the question, so others understand the problem and can help.